# C# IF /ELSE create directory problem

Tags: c#

I'm gettign the error: Error    2   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Here is the code:

```
string masterdin = (@"K:\Drams\Cluse\" +"\\"+"Aia_Gn"+"\\"+Environment.UserName+"\\"+textBox1.Text);
        if(Directory.Exists(masterdin))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This Export set already exists, please rename your Export set");
            textBox1.Clear();

        }
        else(System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(masterdin));
```

The error exists on this line : else(System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(masterdin));

Can someone point out how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string masterdin = (@"K:\Drams\Cluse\" +"\\"+"Aia_Gn"+"\\"+Environment.UserName+"\\"+textBox1.Text);
        if(Directory.Exists(masterdin))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This Export set already exists, please rename your Export set");
            textBox1.Clear();

        }
        else 
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(masterdin);
```

Don't put parenthesis around the CreateDirectory (the edited version in this post fixes that issue).

Answer (score 2):

```
string masterdin = @"K:\Drams\Cluse\" + "\\" + "Aia_Gn" + "\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\" + textBox1.Text;
if(Directory.Exists(masterdin)) {
   MessageBox.Show("This Export set already exists, please rename your Export set");
   textBox1.Clear();
} else {
   Directory.CreateDirectory(masterdin);
}
```

I recommend keeping your curly braces consistent. Also function blocks are always defined by { } in C# (even for lambdas with more than one line of code in them).

Answer (score 1):

You've put the else statement in round brackets instead of curly ones. Change to:

```
else
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(masterdin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

{} not () for your else block

```
else
{
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(masterdin);
}
```

or nothing at all

```
else System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(masterdin);
```

else is not a method!